# Draw without lifting / going on the same line?

Tags: pencil-and-paper-games

Draw this without lifting / going on the same line the following figure.[image]

Comment: @PeregrineRook no , this figure solution is possible

Comment: You're splitting hairs.  Equivalent questions have been asked and answered before, presenting the theory of how ***questions like this*** are answered.  Nothing remains but counting, which is a math exercise and not a puzzle. Besides, [your figure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2ow35.png) is ***not*** solvable [because it has four odd vertices](http://i.stack.imgur.com/86pv5.png).

Comment: @PeregrineRook fyi, this figure is solvable , see the solution by meta45 below.

Comment: @AmruthA: No, it's not, since you drew it poorly. The / diagonal needs to be farther left at the bottom for it to be solvable - otherwise, you miss the middle portion between the two intersections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is an **Eulerian Path**. Euler said:
>
> Theorem: If a network has more than two odd vertices, it does not have an Euler path.
>
> Euler also proved this:
>
> Theorem: If a network has two or zero odd vertices, it has at least one Euler path. In particular, if a network has exactly two odd vertices, then its Euler paths can only start on one of the odd vertices, and end on the other.

Solution:

> Is solvable. As this has 2 odd vertices, you should start in one of them and end on the other. (top and bottom vertices)

Answer (score 4):

Below here one of the many solutions:

> [image: Image1]

Comment: hide the image with >!